# How do go package paths work when the directory is different?

Tags: go

I am doing some light hacking on the [rclone](https://github.com/ncw/rclone) project, and I'm somewhat new to go. I have cloned the repository in my home directory, `/home/poundifdef/rclone`.

When I look at the file, `rclone.go`, in the top-level directory, I see the following import statement:

```
package main

import (
  _ "github.com/ncw/rclone/backend/all"
    "github.com/ncw/rclone/cmd"
  _ "github.com/ncw/rclone/cmd/all"
)
```

My question is this: nowhere in this code, as far as I can tell, do we specify that the `github.com/ncs/rclone/*` packages are supposed to refer to the local versions of these directories. Nowhere in my filesystem have I used a directory called `github.com/ncw`. And yet, running `go run rclone.go` is able to execute this code.

Where is the path `github.com/ncw/rclone` being mapped to my local directory, given these packages, as named, do not exist?

Comment: Yes, it should be in your `$GOPATH/src` directory

Comment: It isn't, though!

poundifdef@rclone-dev:~$ pwd
/home/poundifdef
poundifdef@rclone-dev:~$ find ./ | grep ncw | grep cmd
poundifdef@rclone-dev:~$

Comment: What is your `$GOPATH` ?

Comment: It is not defined. I just have the go binary in `/home/poundifdef/go/bin/go`

Comment: What does `go env` show ?

Comment: Please read How to Write Go Code and _stick_ _to_ _it_. There is no need to complicate things just because it can be made complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

github.com/ncw/rclone is a [module](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules), because it has a [file named `go.mod`](https://github.com/ncw/rclone/blob/master/go.mod) at the repository root. Since you have `$GOPATH` unset, the experimental module feature is enabled.

Where modules are placed in your filesystem is irrelevant. when constructing import paths, all directory names in the module are appended to the module name. The module name is defined in the first line of `go.mod`, here "github.com/ncw/rclone". So the package in `./cmd` has the import path `github.com/ncw/rclone/cmd`.

Commands such as `go build`, `go install`, `go test`, etc. download all other required packages automatically  to `$HOME/go/pkg/mod`, unless the `-mod=vendor` flag is specified, in which case the sources in `vendor` are used.

Comment: Ah, okay, this all makes a ton of sense. Also, now I know that the `GO111MODULE=on` env variable will enable this too. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Golang has an internal mechanism to resolve import path.

This mechanism relies on the existence of several variables on your computer, GOROOT, GOPATH and for old releases GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT.

When the compiler meet a package path, it performs a look up with those paths

- GOROOT/src/[import path]
- GOPATH/src/[import path]
- cwd/vendor/[import path]

The longest path wins and is selected for further processing.

GOROOT is the path to the stdlib.
GOPATH is the path to your local workspace.

For all the details https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/25719-go15vendor.md

This all depends on the setup of your computer, so carefully check `go env` output.

Comment: Your answer is missing Go modules and builds outside of GOPATH.

Comment: yes i have not added those two as i have not yet switch to go module, so i don t know the details well enough. For build outside gopath, in my understanding its the same as go mod